# Como fazer para pegar dados de um arquivos com o fscanf, em c?

Tags: c, c++

**Código:**

```
while(fscanf(arq,"%d %d %d\n\r",x[i],y[i],raio[i])!=EOF){
    cout<<x[i]<<endl;
    i++;
}
```

**Conteudo do arquivo:**

> ```
> mdb236rl    D   CALC B 912 2247 58
> mdb240rl    D   CALC B 1752 776 95
> mdb244rm    D   CIRC B 1940 1209 209
> mdb248rl    F   CALC B 1805 1836 42
> mdb252rm    F   CALC B 2743 1318 94
> ```

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece, ou qual o resultado das variáveis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisa ler o texto antes dos números con `fscanf()`.

`fscanf()` vai começar buscando um número (por causa do `%d` no começo do texto de formatação) e logo encontra `mdb236r1`, que não é número. Então, sendo que não pode ler como número, falha com `EOF`.

Eu acho que algo como

```
char tmp[100];
while( fscanf(arq,"%s %s %s %s %d %d %d\n\r",tmp,tmp,tmp,tmp,x[i],y[i],raio[i]) != EOF ){
    cout<<x[i]<<endl;
    i++;
}
```

deve funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado.
Pensei que ia pegar somente os valores que tivessem no padrão que declarava no fscanf, mas tem que colocar igual tem no arquivo, e depois só pega os relevantes.
Obrigado